# Loading JSON file that changes periodically in server

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit, configmap

My webapp imports a JSON file containing a list of strings which is used as a prop for a select dropdown. The application runs as a node server in a Kubernetes cluster and this JSON file is set as a file mount from a `ConfigMap`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: items
data:
  items.json: |-
    ["a", "b"]
```

Inside the project i've put the file under in `project/static/items.json`, when the project is built, `items.json` is put in `build/client/items.json`

So the ConfigMap mounts `items.json` at `/app/build/client/items.json` inside the container

Now. The issue here is that any changes to `items.json` file, via ConfigMap or manually inside the container has no effect on the application data because at build time, SvelteKit imports the JSON into a variable inside some `xxxx.js` file inside `build/server/` folder

- At first I was loading the JSON inside `+page.server.js`

```
import items from '../../static/items.json';

export async function load() {
  return {
    values: items
  };
}
```

- Tried changing to `+page.js` for client side loading
  Same result
- Tried importing the JSON inside the component

But all the above result in the compiler including the JSON data inside the application build code.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or is there a way to tell the build compiler to ignore this JSON file?

Comment: feel free to update the status of the question if any of below answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

When importing json using `import from` syntax the data is bundled into the javascript files.
So for changes to that file to take effect, a rebuild is required.

Generally you'll have an api or database for the dynamic parts like those select options.

You can also load json files on the server using [fs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/fs.html) when using @sveltejs/adapter-node:
The tricky part is knowing the location of the json file.

```
// +page.server.js
import fs from "node:fs/promises";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";

export const prerender = false;

export function load() {
  return {
    items: fs
      .readFile(staticPath("items.json", import.meta.url), "utf-8")
      .then((contents) => JSON.parse(contents)),
  };
}

function staticPath(path: string, from: string) {
  const filepath = fileURLToPath(from);
  const src = filepath.indexOf("/src/");
  if (src !== -1) {
    // vite dev
    return `${filepath.slice(0, src)}/static/${path}`;
  }
  const server = filepath.indexOf("/server/chunks/");
  if (server !== -1) {
    // adapter node
    return `${filepath.slice(0, server)}/client/${path}`;
  }
  throw new Error("Could not detect static folder");
}
```

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  export let data;
</script>

{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

Note that this relies on the file structure the adapter generates, which is an implementation detail that **can change in future versions**.

Using an environment variable with the location of the json file is a safer option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [node-watch](https://github.com/yuanchuan/node-watch)

```
var watch = require('node-watch');

watch('app/build/client/items.json', { recursive: true }, function(evt, name) {
  console.log('%s changed.', name);
});
```

Once file is read and you got the changes you can **export** that var to **env** or handle file content as per need.